# how to save HTTP_Basic_Authenticate parameters to a user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, basic-authentication

I have a basic application that I want user to be able to access only if they have an access_token I have given them. In this example lets say the token is '131313'

Users without the access_token can only access the index page...

In my User model I have the following columns

```
name:
access_token:
items:
```

In my controller I have:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "??not sure???", access_token: "131313", except: :index
```

I want verification that the right access token is passed '131313' and then to check the name provided by the user and list all of the items associated to that user.

i.e get redirected to a page that has the following

```
@user.each do |user|
  user.item
```

I am guessing I will need a controller with something like:

```
@user = User.find(params[:name])
```

To set my user instance variable for my view and find them by the name provided. What I am having trouble here is understanding if its possible to do this with HTTP_Basic_Authentication. Is there a way to fetch the values provided(i.e 'name')and compare(i.e .find call) them to the database or even add them to the database(i.e .save call)?

Or would I have to roll out a full authentication system?

Comment: You have included a `devise` tag, but you didn't mention it in your question. Is your `User` model created with the `devise` gem?

Comment: where is the devise tag? No there is no devise..

Answer (score 0):

You add something like the following to your `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :authenticate, except: :index

private
  attr_reader   :current_user
  helper_method :current_user

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('MyApplication') do |name, token|
      @current_user = User.find_by(name: name)
      current_user && current_user.access_token == token
    end
  end
```

That `current_user` method returns always the user currently logged in. That means you can that write something like the following in the view without loading an `@user` again:

```
  <%= current_user.name %> 
  <% current_user.items.each do |item| %>
    <%= item.name %>
  <% end %>
```